# How to use data in a timerseries update message

Tags: thingsboard

I use a 'New update timeseries' widget to update a Temperature value.
How can I extract the Temperature value from the Timeseries update message?
f.e. I want to create a new value: msg.temperature2 = msg.temperature + 5

In the rule chain I intercept the update timeseries message with a "Timeseries update

Message:
{
"timeseries": [{
"ts": 1651399784349,
"values": {
"Temperature": 30
}
}]
}

Images:
[Rule chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTSod.png)
[Transformation script-test script function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ucBr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of referencing the value correctly. See below for example.

```js
let msg = {
  "timeseries": [{
    "ts": 1234,
    "values":{
      "Temperature": 30
    }
  }]
}

// The code
var newMsg = msg
newMsg.timeseries[0].values.Temperature2 = newMsg.timeseries[0].values.Temperature + 5

// Remove log, uncomment return
console.log({ "msg": newMsg, "metadata": {} })
//return { "msg": msg, "metadata": {} }
```